# Allow < and > in query string

Tags: c#, webforms

We have a webshop written in ASP.net WebForms where you can filter your search results on price. Some prices are < 1.25 € and that translates in the querystring as <+1.25 or %3c+1.25. When I try to access the webshop with that filter I just get a 404 error without any detailed information.

Can anyone help?

Comment: use `&gt;` for > and 
`&lt;` for <

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This SO post should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: Are you automatically applying the querystring to your data with no validation whatsoever? If you're having problems with < and > either encode it or use something else.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Here's a reference for url-encoding, what's the url when you apply filters?

Comment: Alternatively, you can change the filter's name. (Less than 1.25EUR etc.)

Comment: Sadly that is not possible.